# Get maximum, minimum timestamp values from table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, aggregate-functions

EDIT: Looked at the suggestions in the comments.

The table in question (`gas_station_information_history`) is about 5GB.

The log file of starting the server, running a working query, and then running a MAX, MIN query is:

```
2020-02-03 12:39:54.931 CET [18022] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-03 12:38:55 CET
2020-02-03 12:39:54.936 CET [18020] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18020] LOG:  background worker "parallel worker" (PID 18040) was terminated by sig$
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18020] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT MAX(date), MIN(date)
        FROM gas_station_information_history;
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18020] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18038] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18038] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the $
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18038] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repe$
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18031] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18031] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the $
2020-02-03 12:40:26.615 CET [18031] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repe$
2020-02-03 12:40:26.616 CET [18027] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-03 12:40:26.616 CET [18027] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the $
2020-02-03 12:40:26.616 CET [18027] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repe$
2020-02-03 12:40:26.619 CET [18020] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2020-02-03 12:40:26.685 CET [18041] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-03 12:39:54$
2020-02-03 12:40:26.748 CET [18041] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in pro$
2020-02-03 12:40:26.751 CET [18041] LOG:  redo starts at 3/F92C228
2020-02-03 12:40:26.751 CET [18041] LOG:  invalid record length at 3/F92C260: wanted 24, got 0
2020-02-03 12:40:26.751 CET [18041] LOG:  redo done at 3/F92C228
2020-02-03 12:40:26.784 CET [18020] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18020] LOG:  background worker "parallel worker" (PID 18053) was terminated by sig$
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18020] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT MAX(date), MIN(date)
        FROM gas_station_information_history;
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18020] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18051] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18051] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the $
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18051] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repe$
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18049] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18049] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the $
2020-02-03 12:40:28.959 CET [18049] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repe$
2020-02-03 12:40:28.960 CET [18045] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-03 12:40:28.960 CET [18045] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the $
2020-02-03 12:40:28.960 CET [18045] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repe$
2020-02-03 12:40:28.964 CET [18020] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2020-02-03 12:40:29.038 CET [18054] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-03 12:40:26$
2020-02-03 12:40:29.092 CET [18057] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2020-02-03 12:40:29.114 CET [18058] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2020-02-03 12:40:29.117 CET [18054] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in pro$
2020-02-03 12:40:29.121 CET [18054] LOG:  invalid record length at 3/F92C2D8: wanted 24, got 0
2020-02-03 12:40:29.121 CET [18054] LOG:  redo is not required
2020-02-03 12:40:29.154 CET [18020] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-02-03 12:40:33.868 CET [18020] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-02-03 12:40:33.869 CET [18020] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-02-03 12:40:33.870 CET [18066] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2020-02-03 12:40:33.871 CET [18020] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 18064) exited w$
2020-02-03 12:40:33.873 CET [18059] LOG:  shutting down
2020-02-03 12:40:33.916 CET [18020] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I couldn't find anything online on the `background worker "parallel worker" was terminated by sig$`.

Running `EXPLAIN` on the query gives:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1034772.50..1034772.51 rows=1 width=16)
  ->  Gather  (cost=1034772.28..1034772.49 rows=2 width=16)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1033772.28..1033772.29 rows=1 width=16)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on gas_station_information_history  (cost=0.00..895677.85 rows=27618885 width=8)
JIT:
  Functions: 5
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

---

How can I get the first and last recorded timestamp with time zone out of a table in postgresql? The timestamp column name is "date".

I've tried

```
SELECT MAX(date), MIN(date)
FROM tablename;
```

Which disconnects me: "This socket has been ended by the other party". 
I've also tried

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 10;
```

I've looked at max, min and timestamp resources, which for example suggest

```
SELECT MAX (date) AS "Max Date" 
FROM orders;
```

Which gives the same disconnect error.

How can I make this simple query? Thanks!

Comment: This is a simple query, but it sounds like the table in question is rather sizeable and in need of better indexes, or the DBA has nerfed the max execution time and needs to increase it.

Comment: This should not happen. Did you set `statement_timeout` to a small value? Are you running OOM on the server because of a large sort? Check the PostgreSQL server log file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I researched memory/processing settings and increased work_mem, maintenance_work_mem, and shared_bufffers. I have `statement_timeout` disabled. Here is the log from starting the server, running a working query and then running the `MAX(date)` query. Edit: had to post log in a new reply, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your hint, JohnHC. Better indexing solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding an index on the date column. Thanks for your help!